# Some Git questions

Tags: git, github

I'm starting to learn GitHub, and I have a few questions:

1. How do I remotely remove files from my GitHub repo but keep them on my local machine?
2. How do I upload ONLY .c files when my directory also has .out and .sh?

I'm not sure what to do still, so I:

```
git init
git add *.c
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add url_to_my_repo
git push -u origin master
```

Where do I make it not upload the .out and .sh files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I remotely remove files from my github repo but keep them on my local machine.

`git rm --cached` the files, then commit.

> How do I upload ONLY .c files when my directory also has .out and .sh?

This is controlled when doing `git add`. If you add a .c file, it will be committed to the repository, and it will be uploaded. If you add a .sh file, it will be uploaded.

Remove the files using `git rm --cached`, add two lines saying `*.out` and `*.sh` to the `.gitignore` file, add the ignore file itself to the repository, then commit.

Note that `.gitignore` is only for convenience when doing mass-`git add`; it prevents accidentally adding an "ignored" file, but it *will not* automagically erase the files from your repository. If you have added a file earlier, it will remain tracked until manually `git rm`'d.

Comment: Thanks you. I'll try this in a moment and if it works, mark yours as the answer. If not, I'll ask more questions!

Comment: Since this appears to be a dead question, I will mark your answer as solved because it **was** helpful. I still don't fully understand how a gitignore file works or what to put in it, but I appear to have this semi-functional.

Comment: @asdfa https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files